# My images are horizontally stacked, and I don't know how I did it?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Ok, so here is an interesting question that I am banging my head against a wall trying to figure out.  I am currently building my portfolio site and I am in school, but I created a very ugly site a year ago.  In this old site I have a bunch of images that are text aligned center and respond perfectly.  Meaning when you shrink the screen the images stack centered and they are all horizontally stuck together.

So I usually use a float left and margins to do this, but in this code there is just margin-left: auto, margin-right: auto, width 100%, and text-align: center....

So my question is how are these images stacking horizontally?  I have tried to replicate this just with a rough draft and my divs just stack vertically on top of each other.

Please if anyone can explain how this is possible I would appreciate it greatly.

Here is the html

```
<div id="container">
<div id="portfolio">
<br>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/Bottle Beer Mockups.jpg"><img src="images/3DudesBrew300x150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/GreatBankMockUp.jpg"><img src="images/GreatBank300x150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/BabyShowerMockUp.jpg"><img src="images/BabyShower300x150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/JayhawkPosterFramed.jpg"><img src="images/Jayhawk300x150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/JohnGlaser5kPoster.jpg"><img src="images/JohnGlaser300x150.jpg"class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/MagazineOpenMockup.jpg"><img src="images/BoyScouts300x150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/PissingDogInFrame.jpg"><img src="images/PissingDog300x150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/LostWorldTylerReardon.jpg"><img src="images/LostWorld300X150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/BelmarRisingBeach4.jpg"><img src="images/BelmarRising300x150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="images/SharonStrineMockUp.jpg"><img src="images/SharonStrine300x150.jpg" class="workSpace"></a>

</div>
</div>
```

and here is the css

```
 .thumbnail{
z-index: 0;
 }

  #portfolio{
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:#CCC;
text-align:center;
}

 #container{
width:100%;
background-color:#000;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
 }
 .workSpace{
width:250px;
padding: 3px;
}

.workSpace:hover{
opacity:.4;
transition: 1s;
}

a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;  
}
```

Comment: Well, `<a>` elements are `inline` elements.

Comment: What @TylerH means is that `inline` elements are treated like blocks of text in HTML.  So when your screen shrinks, the images behave like text would when the screen shrinks.  Once the screen reaches a certain size, it can only keep one of these "characters" on a line, so that's how they appear.

Comment: jsfiddle.net

Although as mentioned above - anchor tags are inline; try setting a to display: block;

Answer (score 0):

The `display` property of an element defines how it flows in the document. `a` is an inline element, meaning it is intended to flow *in line* with text, and is treated as such. On the other hand, `div` is block element, meaning it is intended to define the layout of the document. This results in each `div` flowing farther down the document by default.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you can also change the `display` property. `inline` and `block` are the two most basic properties, but there are others: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: I'm not sure if I unintentionally selected an option do to so, but could someone explain why this answer became community wiki?

Comment: If you didn't make it a community wiki, then the system probably did it. You can ask a question about that over on meta.